# Pass data safely from view to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, url, hyperlink, link-to

I want to pass data from a view (link) to a controller so it can look up the related information. Services for a company, in this case.

I see examples where people have added to params like this:

```
<div>
    <%= link_to 'Services', :controller => 'company', :action => 'services', :company_id => @company.id %>
</div>
```

...but that results in a transparent (unsafe) URL like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/company/services?company_id=17
```

Is there a way to get around this without stuffing data into the Session? What's the best practice on links inside an app that requires authentication?

Comment: What's unsafe about the URL?

Comment: You need authorization, not just authentication. You can also use GUIDs instead of straight IDs, but there's nothing wrong with exposing data like this if your app has proper auth/auth in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere is no such major harm in passing data like this in View.

Still if you insist on having, then check prettyurls:

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid
```

Prior to we must have valid checks in controller & model files.

```
 1. Valid Checks and redirection in Controller is helpful.
 2. Depending on need adding validations in model can be a good support.
```

Comment: Pretty URLs aren't any different, though, you're still uniquely identifying an entity. The issue is whether or not the user I is authorized to view, modify, etc. what they're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(:id => Base64.encode64("1")) %>
```

and in your controller

```
def new
  id=Base64.decode64(params[:id].to_s)
end
```

this is another form for create a link with data

check your routes with command un console rake routes

for more information read this documention

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: if you dont need for the value visible in url using a Base64 in request for METHOD GET the parameters go in url  forever and one link_to work with GET METHOD

Comment: No doubt Base64 will work, but in a real rails application how/where we are going to wrap this encode & decode functions ?

Comment: is for encode data work in all project for example where encoding? in your send data, where decoding? in your get a post params action for controller,i am using in all links to my server per more secure data

Comment: but where to place this encode/decode logic in a real time rails applciation ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68779/discussion-between-ajay-and-luis).

Comment: i don't understand fine your question, but if your question refer to where you enable using in real time decode/encode data, this working in views and action controller and this execute when load your view or your action